# How to close the Html5 dialog

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

At first, I get a dialog in my html

```
<dialog open>
  <button id="close">Close</button>
</dialog>
```

And then, I need a JS function to close or hide it.

How to do it ?

Also i have a submit button to show the dialog.
How to show it ?

```
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" id="show" />
```

Comment: The <dialog> tag is currently only supported in Chrome, and Safari 6. so in which browser you are working?

Comment: why don't you use costume dialog rather using HTML5-dialog, because most of the browser doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation draft for the `<dialog>` HTML5 tag is available here: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element

Basically you can use the `show()` and `close()` methods to interact with the dialog.

Check this tutorial for an example: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/a-preview-of-the-new-dialog-element

Make sure that you enabled this feature in Chrome:

> Once you have Chrome Canary installed go to chrome://flags and enable the Enable experimental Web Platform features flag. You will need to restart the browser for the change to take effect.

Comment: thanks for ur links ...and i try to do it ..when i click on my button..nothing happened...do you have any example or any codes show me ? thanks :)

Comment: Did you enable the `Web Platform features` in Chrome ? (see my edit)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
<dialog id="dialog">
  <p>Hi, I'm a dialog!</p>
  <button id="close">Okay</button>
</dialog>

<button id="show">Show Dialog</button>
```

JS script

```
var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
var showBtn = document.getElementById('show');
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');

// Setup an event listener for the show button.
showBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Show the dialog.
  dialog.show();
});

// Setup an event listener for the close button.
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Close the dialog.
  dialog.close();
});
```

for more details see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/a-preview-of-the-new-dialog-element